# Load JSON data on 2 different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

i need to load the content of 2 different .json files in 2 different divs.

```
<div class="box1">First</div>
<div class="box2">Second</div>
```

first.json

```
{
"item": {
    "name": "Pippo",
    "details": "Red",
    "composition": "Sweet",
    "modelDetails": [
        "Red",
        "Yellow",
        "Green"
    ],
    "images": [
        "http://cdn.test.biz/42/42266674ce_12n_f.jpg",
        "http://cdn.test.biz/42/42266674ce_12n_r.jpg",
        "http://cdn.test.biz/42/42266674ce_12n_e.jpg",
        "http://cdn.test.biz/42/42266674ce_12n_d.jpg"
    ]
}
}
```

second.json

```
{
"item": {
    "name": "Fill",
    "details": "Black",
    "composition": "Hard",
    "modelDetails": [
        "Red",
        "Yellow",
        "Green"
    ],
    "images": [
        "http://cdn.test.biz/42/42266674ce_12n_d.jpg",
        "http://cdn.test.biz/42/42266674ce_12n_s.jpg",
        "http://cdn.test.biz/42/42266674ce_12n_f.jpg",
        "http://cdn.test.biz/42/42266674ce_12n_v.jpg"
    ]
}
}
```

it's possible with jQuery or Angular? 
I tried with this:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
{{ x.Name }}
</li>
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
{{ x.Details }}
</li>
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
{{ x.Composizione }}
</li>
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
{{ x.moreDetails }}
</li>
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
{{ x.photo1 }}
</li>
</ul>

</div>
                        </div>
                        <script>
function customersController($scope,$http) {
$http.get("assets/data/five.json")

.success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
}
</script>
</div>
```

...but i have problems with the images load...i visualize the textual url and not the real image...

Comment: If you have already tried, show us what you've done and explain the problems that you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not defining 2 controllers one for each div with a respective factory fetching your json. or if you rather want to have only one controller you can fetch the json and assign it to different models in the $scope of this controller. Such as

```
$scope.first  = parsedJsonData1
$scope.second = parsedJsonData2
```

within your divs you can then use ng-repeat to iterate over each models data

> ..but i have problems with the images load...i visualize the textual url and not the real image.

because you have to render an image tag which uses your models data.attribute as url
try something like (given that photo1 contains the url):

```
 <img ng-src="{{x.photo1}}"/>
```

Comment: The attribute for the img works! Thanks! 
How i can set the controller with the 2 json?

    function customersController($scope,$http) {
    $http.get("assets/data/five.json")
    
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});

Comment: if i try to duplicate this in the others div I see only the first json not the others

Comment: you know how i can modify to load the second .json in the second div? thanks

Comment: you should have a look at angular factories / services, see http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var firstJson='first.json' // and full path
 $.getJSON(firstJsonPath, function (data) {

jQuery('.box1').html(JSON.stringify(data)); // for example

    });

var secontJson='second.json' // and full path
 $.getJSON(secontJson, function (data) {

jQuery('.box2').html(JSON.stringify(data)); // for example


    });
```

Comment: Thanks! But what i need to set in v.item.name?

Comment: set your want data in div this for example

Comment: You want write all data in div?

Comment: Yes, all the data of the .json

Comment: try this jQuery('.box2').html(JSON.stringify(data))